# Spark Python save output from list created

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am new to Spark, I have some files to read as the input in gridded format which looks like this: 
 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 6.16 6.32 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999

I want to collect and rearrange the data in some way then append it to a multi tuple list for example in the format:`[[category, year, month, value]]` The year and month data is extracted from the file path. 
 The code I have so far is this but it does not work as I know there is an error with the .collect() line since you cannot use collect on a list:

```
combinedList = []
yearRange = ["2007-2011"]

for i in yearRange:
    for year in range (2007, 2012):
        strYear = str(year)
        for month in range(1,13): 
            strMonth = str(month) # convert to string
            finalMonth = strMonth.zfill(2) # add 0 on left
            #MaxTemp as category. There are other categories too
            path = os.path.abspath("/input/MaxTemp_"+i+"/MaxTemp_"+strYear+"-"+finalMonth+"_ACTUAL.txt")
            if os.path.exists(path):
                textFile = sc.textFile(path)

                # split word in line from file
                value = textFile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) 

                # collect the year and month from file path and word to input into list
                combinedList.append([strYear, finalMonth, value])
                #print combinedList

                # need to output the combinedList
                wc = combinedList.collect()
wc.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("output")
```

Ignoring the category part for now, I need to split the words in the files and have it correspond to the year and month from the file it is reading from. Therefore the output should be in list format:
 `MaxTemp, 2007, 02, 12.4`
`MaxTemp, 2009, 12, 5.3`
 `...`
 So my problem is I'm not sure which Spark functions to use to have my output in the way I want - as a list.

Comment: 1. yes, but can you show an example?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I have edited my question to elaborate on the problem at hand. I hope this help?

Comment: You need to show the input and output desired

Comment: I have added the input